# Why was this Suggested Edit rejected at last?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I got [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326552/matlab-cdfplof-do-not-show-complete-graph-when-multiple-cdfs-are-plotted-in-one) in Triage review and later, I added the pictures of the plotted graphs and fixed indentation of the code and made the title a question. But [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9972041) was rejected.

Why was the Suggested Edit rejected?

Is it my fault or the reviewers' fault?

Comment: I think your description of the change should have been better, including something like "went to the trouble of plotting out the OPs data-points on a graph". As long as the graph is actually useful to the question, that was putting in some extra effort on our part. Without knowing why the graph had magically appeared, I'd have been scratching my head on the review.

Comment: @BillWoodger You have option to see the 'markdown'. So, the graph had not appeared magically. In fact, a reviewer can not say this! Thanks.

Comment: @BillWoodger promote your comment to an answer, please. You could add that removing the image description was not needed. We have some blind users, they obviously require the description to make sense of the image. In that sense the edit made the post not better in quality.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the markdown. What I'm saying is that you should have included "I made that" in the text of your comment for the edit, which is there to help reviewers.

Comment: "our part" was "your part". I was saying, as long as useful to the question, it was a really great thing for you to plot the points. But. If I see an image and the edit comment is "just some formatting" I'm just not going to accept it. If you don't claim credit I'm going to wonder if it is rude, or spam, or useless to the question. All of which I'd need to spend more time on, so I wouldn't (unless the rest of the edit were particularly brilliant to the question).

Comment: @BillWoodger are you sure that our OP didn't just inline the images included in the other OP's question (due to the latter having insufficient rep)? And manetsus: I probably would have approved of your edit, but editing the title yet leaving "*cdfplof do not show*" in it makes me unsure.

Answer (score 27):

As mentioned by @BillWoodger in the comments, your edit suggestion on the question itself is very good. However, your edit summary ("improved formatting") is insufficient. Personally, I would have accepted your suggested edit. However, I'm not surprised that other reviewers rejected it.

Unfortunately, reviewers see the phrase "improved formatting" too often and on any kind of suggested edit. Especially on extended edits it isn't a proper description and is therefore frowned upon as lazy commenting by a significant number of reviewers.

I think, your edit summary should have described in more detail what you did and best why you did it. For example, you could have written something like this:

> turned title into a question, fixed includes of images so that they become visible, formatted text before code and images as headlines so that the structure of the post becomes clearer, fixed indentation of code, removed asking for help and appreciation

This would have helped the reviewers to understand what your edit was about and I guess that with this edit summary your edit would have been approved.

Comment: "it doesn't describe anything" I must disagree on this point; it describes exactly what you did when paired with actually looking at the post. Please don't reject suggested edits based on this alone.

Comment: @TylerH I agree that it is enough when the edit is only improving the formatting. But when the edit does other things as well? While I would not reject an edit just based on a bad summary, it might lead to misunderstandings that would make me reject an edit because it makes no sense to me.

Comment: To expand on this: if you convert a link to an image, **you should always say you did that in the edit reason**. Period. Because you can't easily tell that's what happened when reviewing. The markdown view only shows the additional of an exclamation point, which is hard to catch. And the rendered view highlights the text in red so you can't tell it was a link, and it looks like you inserted a random image. Never rely on vague "improved formatting" reasons when inserting an image. @TylerH

Comment: @animuson I didn't suggest that anyone rely on "improved formatting" as a catch-all, only that one shouldn't reject an edit simply because "improved formatting" is what's written in the edit description. They should approve or reject based on the edits themselves, 100% of the time.

Comment: @TylerH: Maybe "it doesn't describe anything" is a bit harsh. I will improve my wording. Personally, I wouldn't have rejected the suggested edit in question. I usually inspect all modifications carefully. However, I'm not surprised if a complete edit is rejected by other reviewers if the summary just says "improved formatting".

Comment: I like the fourth edition of this answer much better.

Comment: Wait... revision messages mean something? Since when does anyone care about those?

Comment: I wouldn't reject an edit just for having a bad edit message, but my experience is that good edit messages are strongly correlated with good edits, and bad edit messages are weakly correlated with bad edits, and that subconsciously affects my judgement of the edit.  I'm not surprised that other reviewers are applying Bayes' theorem in a similar way.